# Flattening nested string list in python

Tags: python, list, csv, nested, flatten

I have two lists, one is not nested, the other is.

```
carNames = []
priceAndMileage = []
```

Data looks like this, combined:

```
[(u'2011 Toyota Camry SE V6', [u'$14,995', u'31,750']), (u'2012 Toyota Camry L', [u'$15,993', u'27,381'])]
```

My code is:

```
combinedData = zip(carNames, priceAndMileage)

writer = csv.writer(open("dict.csv", 'r+'))

for dataList in combinedData:
    dataList = [dataList[0]] + [y for x in dataList[1] for y in x]
    writer.writerow(dataList)
```

I flattened the dataList, however it iterates over EVERY character, instead of just the item. How I can I produce results such as the flatten task does not flatten each character, but just the item sub-list?

And my result is in the csv file:

```
2011 Toyota Camry SE V6,$,1,4,",",9,9,5,3,1,",",7,5,0
2012 Toyota Camry L,$,1,5,",",9,9,3,2,7,",",3,8,1
```

But I need:

```
2011 Toyota Camry SE V6, $14,995, 31,750
2012 Toyota Camry L, $15,993, 27,381
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flatten `dataList` you can concatenate `[dataList[0]]` and `dataList[1]`:

```
   for dataList in combinedData:
        dataList = [dataList[0]] + dataList[1]
        writer.writerow(dataList)
```

**Explanation**

dataList is, e.g, `(u'2011 Toyota Camry SE V6', [u'$14,995', u'31,750'])`
(by the way `dataList` is not a `list`, it's a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) - basically an immutable version of list)

What we want to get is a flattened `dataList`, i.e, `[u'2011 Toyota Camry SE V6', u'$14,995', u'31,750']`.

`[dataList[0]]` is a list with only one element: `[u'2011 Toyota Camry SE V6']`

`dataList[1]` is a list with two elements: `[u'$14,995', u'31,750']`

`[dataList[0]] + dataList[1]` will concatenate these two lists and we'll get the flattened `dataList`.

Comment: @ChristopherWallace In your list comprehension you essentially had a double for loop, so you were iterating over the list to get two strings, then iterating over each of the two strings and getting each character of them.